# Have any of the Star Wars aliens been referred to by their action figure names in-universe?

Tags: star-wars

When the original Kenner line of *Star Wars* action figures was released in the late 1970s/early 1980s, not every character and/or alien had a proper name yet. Because of this, the manufacturers had to come up with names of their own, so they often made one up based solely on the appearance of the character. This includes:

- Walrus Man (Ponda Baba/Aqualish)
- Hammerhead (Momaw Nedon/Ithorian)
- Snaggletooth (Takeel/Zutton/Snivvian)
- Yak Face (Saelt-Marae/Yarkora)
- Prune Face (Orrimaarko/Dressellian)

Have any of these terms been used to describe members of the species in-universe, either canon or legends? The only one that I am aware of is that hammerhead is essentially a racial slur used against Ithorians in canon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hammerhead:

> **Ithorian** The proper name for the species commonly referred to as Hammerheads. The nickname for Ithorians comes from their T-shaped heads that rest atop long, curved necks. They speak Basic with a strange twist because of their two mouths on opposite sides of their necks. This generates one of the most beautiful and difficult to learn languages in the galaxy. <sub>[SWSB]</sub>
>
> <sub>[*Star Wars Encyclopedia* (1998)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Encyclopedia), page 145</sub>

Snaggletooth:

> **Zutton** A Snivvian bounty hunter, like most of his species he is a tortured artist driven to live out the stories he creates. One of this stories led him to an out-of-the-way cantina in Mos Eisley on the little-visited planet of Tatooine. During his stay, he picked up the nickname Snaggletooth because of his pronounced canine fangs. He was on retainer to Jabba the Hutt. <sub>[GG12, SWAJ]</sub>
>
> <sub>[*Star Wars Encyclopedia* (1998)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Encyclopedia), page 354</sub>

Yak Face:

> A dark figure moved silently among the shadows, pausing behind a column here, a statue there. He made his way stealthily along the perimeter of the room, stepping once over a snoring Yak Face. He never made a sound. This was Boushh, the bounty hunter.
>
> <sub>[*Star Wars: Return of the Jedi* (novelization)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_VI:_Return_of_the_Jedi_(novel)?so=search), page 20 of 1st edition paperback</sub>

> **Saelt-Marae** No one knows the true origins, background, or species of the being who calls himself Saelt-Marae, whom some have called Yak Face because of his whiskered, broad-snouted face. (Beings with a similar appearance, who call themselves Yarkora, have been sighted in the Outer Rim territories.)
>
> <sub>[*Star Wars Encyclopedia* (1998)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Encyclopedia), page 256</sub>

Prune Face:

> **Orrimaarko** The real name of the Dresselian nicknamed Prune Face, he was a noted resistance fighter during the war to overthrow the Empire. Orrimaarko was the first of his species to be given command of a Spec-Force team by the Rebel Alliance. The wrinkly skinned humanoid wears an eyepatch and a camouflage cloak. <sub>[GG12]</sub>
>
> <sub>[*Star Wars Encyclopedia* (1998)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Encyclopedia), page 81</sub>

> Some in the galaxy refer to [Dressellians] as "prune faces" because of their wrinkled visage, a nickname that Dressellians disdain.
>
> <sub>[*The New Essential Guide to Alien Species*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_New_Essential_Guide_to_Alien_Species), page 46: Dressellian</sub>

The *Encyclopedia* describes both Ponda Baba and Aqualish in general as "walrus-faced", but I haven't found any mention of "Walrus Man" per se.